# Python float to string: how to get '0.03' but '-.03'

Tags: python, string, floating-point

Is there a quick way to convert a floating point number between -0.99 and +0.99 such that it always takes up 4 characters: ie positive values go to e.g. '0.03' but negative values to e.g. '-.03', without the leading zero?
Obviously I could do

```
s = '%4.2f' % n
if s[0] == '-':
    s = '-%s' % s[2:]
```

but perhaps some stackoverflowers know of a Python shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = ('%4.2f' % n).replace('-0','-')
```

Comment: Ah - of course. That's neater than my way. I don't suppose there's a way to do it if my number is one of many on a single line, is there? There may be other '-0' characters I don't want replaced with '-', you see...

Comment: I guess that depends on what you're trying to do. If your line is `s="0.3 -0.3 -.9` you could do `' '.join(('%2f' % float(n)).replace('-0', '-') for n in s.split())`. I would need more information to give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks - I think I've got it. A big green tick to you, sir!

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could do this:

```
"{0: 3.2f}".format(n)
```

The space indicates that for positive numbers, a space should be printed, and for negative numbers the sign. This way, they always take the same width.

Comment: Thanks, but the number is to go into a field to match that of an existing (old) format and it has to be either a leading zero (positive numbers) or '-' (negative numbers) before the decimal point (no spaces).